# Enumitem label vertical position

Tags: enumitem

How to raise label position using "enumitem" package, in my case
each label should be printed within `\item[•]` or `\item[*]`, need to update template itself?
[image: m]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{testitemize}{itemize}{10}
\setlist[testitemize,1]{label={\raisebox{20pt}{•}},labelsep=4.6bp,leftmargin=*,
itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,labelwidth=0bp,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,rightmargin=0pt,
font={\fontsize{8.5bp}{8.5bp}\selectfont},listparindent=10bp,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{testitemize}
\item[•]  identifying the acquirer
\item[•]  identifying the acquirer
\item[•]  identifying the acquirer
\item[•]  identifying the acquirer
\end{testitemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are specifying the label in the `\setlist` (with a `\raisebox`), but then overriding that when you include the optional parameter to `\item`. So, instead of `\item[•]`, just using `\item` should give you the desired results.

Comment: Yes, raisebox will not work due to given in the optional parameter, how to control or raise "bullet" label inside of \item globally.

Comment: You are already controling it globally for the `testitemize` environment.

Comment: Yes, it will work only if empty label {\item}, how to control when label in the optional argument \item[*]

Comment: If you want to be able to do it locally, using a similar `\raisebox` should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the `setlist` you have

```
label={\raisebox{20pt}{•}}
```

which defines a global label to use for the `testitemize` but then you override it when you use the optional parameter to `\item []`. So, solution is to use `\item`.

[image]

If you want to manually specify it as part of the optional parateter to `\item` then specify the symbol with the `\raisebox` applied.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}    

\newcommand{\MyRaisedBullet}{\raisebox{4pt}{\textbullet}}

\newlist{testitemize}{itemize}{10}
\setlist[testitemize,1]{
    label={\MyRaisedBullet},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{testitemize}
    \item no optional parameter
    \item[\MyRaisedBullet] optional parameter specified
\end{testitemize}

\end{document}
```